# Custom Signup Form Using Mailchimp - Connection could not be established with host mail.yourdomain.com [Operation timed out #60]

Tags: php, html, forms, email, mailchimp

I am trying to have a custom form on my website. The form gathers diet preferences, and upon submit, I'd like to grab that information with their name and email, and add it to a list in Mailchimp. I have setup the list correctly in Mailchimp, and the form is built and styled on my page. I followed the following article, as you can see in my code, based on Mailchimp's recommendation on creating a custom form.

**http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms**

I think I have connected each input to it's corresponding element in the Mailchimp list, but when I hit the submit button, nothing happens for about 20 seconds and then I get the following error:

**Connection could not be established with host mail.yourdomain.com [Operation timed out #60]**

I am currently developing on a local server using MAMP - and feel this may be an issue, but if not what can I do to make this custom form work properly?

```
<form action="https://platesite.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST" class="text-center form-email">
                            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="694035325d6c49e6922fda852">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="e9b40e5d0e">

                            <h4 class="uppercase mt48 mt-xs-0">Tell Us about yourself</h4>
                            <p class="lead mb64 mb-xs-24">
                                Share a little bit about your taste preferences <br>
                        so we can create a plan just for you.
                            </p>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <hr>
                                <h6 class="uppercase">
                                    1. What is your plan preference?
                                </h6>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p class="mb16">
                                        Simply Healthy
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="checkbox-option text-left">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE3" value="Simply Healthy" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p class="mb16">
                                        Paleo
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="checkbox-option text-left">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE3" value="Paleo" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p class="mb16">
                                        Vegetarian
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="checkbox-option text-left">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE3" value="Vegetarian" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p class="mb16">
                                        Gluten-Free
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="checkbox-option text-left">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE3" value="Gluten-Free" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <h6 class="uppercase">
                                        2. How many people are you cooking for?
                                    </h6>
                                    <div class="select-option">
                                        <i class="ti-angle-down"></i>
                                        <select name="MERGE4">
                                            <option selected value="Default">Select An Option</option>
                                            <option value="google">1</option>
                                            <option value="website">2</option>
                                            <option value="friend">3</option>
                                            <option value="friend">4</option>
                                            <option value="friend">5</option>
                                            <option value="other">6</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <h6 class="uppercase">
                                    3. How long do you typically have to prepare meals?
                                </h6>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p>
                                        Less than 20 min. </p>
                                            <div class="radio-option">
                                                <div class="inner"></div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="MERGE5" value="less than 20" />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p>20 - 35 min.</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE5" value="20-35" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p>35 - 60 min.</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE5" value="35-60" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <p>60+ min.</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE5" value="60+" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <h6 class="uppercase">
                                    3. How adventurous are you with cooking?
                                </h6>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <p>
                                        I like simple food, thanks </p>
                                            <div class="radio-option">
                                                <div class="inner"></div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="MERGE6" value="I like simple food, thanks" />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <p>I'll try it if it sounds good</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE6" value="I'll try it if it sounds good" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <p>I'll try anything!</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE6" value="I'll try anything!" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <h6 class="uppercase">
                                    4. What ingredients would you like to avoid?
                                </h6>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>All Dairy</p>
                                            <div class="radio-option">
                                                <div class="inner"></div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="All Dairy" />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Cheese</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Cheese" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Eggs</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Eggs" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Tree Nuts</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Tree Nuts" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Peanuts</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Peanuts" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Soy</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Soy" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Tofu</p>
                                            <div class="radio-option">
                                                <div class="inner"></div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Tofu" />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Beef</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Beef" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Chicken</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Chicken" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Pork</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Pork" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Lamb</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Lamb" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Fish</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Fish" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Shellfish</p>
                                            <div class="radio-option">
                                                <div class="inner"></div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Shellfish" />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Avocado</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Avocado" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Cilantro</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Cilantro" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Bell Pepper</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Bell Pepper" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Mushroom</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Mushroom" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <p>Spicy Food</p>
                                    <div class="radio-option">
                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="MERGE7" value="Spicy Food" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">


                                        <div class="inner"></div>
                                        <input type="text" name="MERGE8" class="col-md-12 " placeholder="Other (list separated by comma)" />

                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <h6 class="uppercase">
                                    3. Your Account Details
                                </h6>
                                <input type="text" name="MERGE1" class="col-md-6  validate-required" placeholder="First Name*" />
                                <input type="text" name="MERGE2" class="col-md-6 validate-required" placeholder="Last Name*" />
                                <input type="text" name="MERGE0" class="col-md-12 validate-required validate-email" placeholder="Your Email Address*" />

                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <h6 class="uppercase">
                                        4. Lastly, how did you hear of us?
                                    </h6>
                                    <div class="select-option">
                                        <i class="ti-angle-down"></i>
                                        <select name="MERGE9">
                                            <option selected value="Default">Select An Option</option>
                                            <option value="google">Google</option>
                                            <option value="website">Facebook</option>
                                            <option value="friend">Instagram</option>
                                            <option value="friend">Friend Referral</option>
                                            <option value="friend">Influencer Referral</option>
                                            <option value="friend">Blog</option>
                                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Subscribe to list">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ht" value="b750d7603dc70714c655f39211d647bec3bed54f:MTQ4MDQ4Nzc0OS44NTIx">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mc_signupsource" value="hosted">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```